# How would you convert this JSON request to a new JSON output in PHP?

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to convert a JSON request into a new JSON output, because I need to rename some of the variables being used in order to work in the calendar. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/  The calendar came with a sample PHP setup to output JSON.

How would I go about having SAMPLE.PHP echo the data as a loop converting the variable names that are in my JSON file to have the same names?

**SAMPLE.PHP = file to setup the Calendar JSON which is called from Jquery**

```
<?php

$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

echo json_encode(array(

    array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => "Event1",
        'start' => "$year-$month-10",
        'url' => "http://www.eventurl.com/1"
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 222,
        'title' => "Event2",
        'start' => "$year-$month-20",
        'end' => "$year-$month-22",
        'url' => "http://www.eventurl.com/2"
    ),

));

?>
```

RESULT:

```
[
{
    "id": 111,
    "title": "Event1",
    "start": "2011-06-10",
    "url": "http://www.eventurl.com/1"
},
{
    "id": 222,
    "title": "Event2",
    "start": "2011-06-20",
    "end": "2011-06-22",
    "url": "http://eventurl.com/2"
}
]
```

**MYJSON = I would like to pull my own data from my own JSON url instead of the data in sample PHP creation (but keeping the sample PHP structure).  Here is the result of my JSON request, and I have taken out many other rows just to clear up clutter on this post- (myUrl.json):**

```
{
"events": [
    {
        "event": {

            "id": 1164038671,
            "title": "TestEvent",
            "start_date": "2011-06-24 13:00:00",
            "end_date": "2011-06-24 16:00:00",
            "url": "ttp://www.eventurl.com/1",

        }
    },
    {
        "event": {

            "id": 1163896245,
            "title": "Test",
            "start_date": "2011-07-14 13:00:00",
            "end_date": "2011-07-14 16:00:00",
            "url": "ttp://www.eventurl.com/2",

        }
    }
]
}
```

**As a test, I am able to retrieve the values like so just for displaying:**

```
<?php 

$string = file_get_contents('myUrl.json');
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

// array method
foreach($json_a[events] as $p)
{
echo '
ID: '.$p[event][id].' <br/>
TITLE: '.$p[event][title].' <br/>
START DATE: '.$p[event][start_date].' <br/>
END DATE: '.$p[event][end_date].' <br/>
URL: '.$p[event][url].' <br/>

<br/><br/>
';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just decode the incoming JSON, manipulate it to be what you'd like, then encode the JSON and print it?

If you need to rename variables (or keys), then set up a `$tmp` variable.
That is,

```
$json_b['key2'] = $json_a['key1'];
```

So, I suppose your code would look something like:

```
<?php 

    $string = file_get_contents('myUrl.json');
    $json_a=json_decode($string,true);
    $json_b = array();

    // array method
    foreach($json_a[events] as $p)
    {
        $json_b[event]['ID'] = $json_a[event][id];
        $json_b[event]['TITLE'] = $json_a[event][title];
        //and so on...
    }

    echo json_encode($json_b);

?>
```